# check whether event occurred in 30-second intervals

Tags: r, datetime, markov-chains

I have the data set with event ID and timestamp when this event happened. For example at 9/2/2019 17:06. I want to build Markov chain model with two states noevent and event. To avoid building continuous time Markov chain, I want to split the period by 30 second and checking if in those 30 seconds event happened or not. Maybe someone could help me how to do it in R? Thank you!

I only prepared the date format and calculated the time between two events as well how many no events happened between two events.

```
data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(data$timestamp,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

nrow <- nrow(data)
for (i in 2:nrow) {
data$diff[i] <- difftime(data$timestamp[i], data$timestamp[i-1], units="secs")}
data$NUm <-round(data$diff/30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### tidyverse solution

Use `lubridate::floor_date()` to round to 30-second intervals and `tidyr::complete()` to fill in intervals with no events:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  mutate(timestamp = floor_date(timestamp, "30 seconds")) %>%
  complete(timestamp = full_seq(timestamp, 30)) %>%
  mutate(
    event = ifelse(!is.na(id), "yes", "no"),
    .keep = "unused"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  timestamp           event
  <dttm>              <chr>
1 2023-02-19 10:01:00 yes  
2 2023-02-19 10:01:30 no   
3 2023-02-19 10:02:00 yes  
4 2023-02-19 10:02:30 no   
5 2023-02-19 10:03:00 no   
6 2023-02-19 10:03:30 no   
7 2023-02-19 10:04:00 no   
8 2023-02-19 10:04:30 yes
```

#### Base R solution

Similar logic as above, using base functions:

```
times <- as.POSIXlt(data$timestamp)
times$sec <- ifelse(times$sec < 30, 0, 30)
intervals <- seq(min(times), max(times), by = 30)
data.frame(
  intervals,
  event = ifelse(intervals %in% as.POSIXct(times), "yes", "no")
)
```

```
            intervals event
1 2023-02-19 10:01:00   yes
2 2023-02-19 10:01:30    no
3 2023-02-19 10:02:00   yes
4 2023-02-19 10:02:30    no
5 2023-02-19 10:03:00    no
6 2023-02-19 10:03:30    no
7 2023-02-19 10:04:00    no
8 2023-02-19 10:04:30   yes
```

##### *Example data*

In the future, it’s best if you include example data in your question. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805). For these solutions, I used:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  timestamp = as.POSIXct(c(
    "2023-02-19 10:01:23",
    "2023-02-19 10:02:01",
    "2023-02-19 10:04:45"
  ))
)
```